# Call C# assembly from Python (in sublime text plugin)

Tags: c#, python, mono, sublimetext2

Is there any way to invoke code from C# assembly (which was compiled with mono compiler) from sublime text plugin which supports python only? Can I use pythonnet or iron python somehow to write sublime text plugin?

Comment: I think you need to use IronPython and import clr. Look at http://remark.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/use-net-classes-in-ironpython/

Comment: How can I force sublime text to use ironpython interpreter for my plugin instead of the default one (for example it's 3.3 embedded in sublime text 3)?

Comment: Hhhhmmm. Short answer: I don't know. Longer answer: Maybe you can write a loader script that runs on the embedded python which then calls Ironpython using the actual plugin (with something like os.system or the subprocess module http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to add language support to sublime text by using the C# code to process the editor contents and send back meta-data (syntax highlighting info, autocomplete options, etc.) then a standard approach would be to wrap the C# code in a separate server process and talk to it over sockets in python.

If on the other hand you're looking to directly modify sublime text's behaviour than this approach won't do much for you.

Some examples of the server approach for extending language support in other editors would be, the [VimClojure](https://github.com/vim-scripts/VimClojure) plugin which talks to a separate java process to add clojure support to vim, or [ENSIME](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime) which connects to a server written in scala to add scala support to emacs.